# Deploy Java EE project to WebSphere 7 WITHOUT Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad

I am getting tired of all the **bugs in eclipse and m2eclipse**, and would like to build with maven using the command prompt, plus afterwards **start the server**, and **deploy the application to the server** and publish it using the **command prompt**. **Normally I do that within eclipse servers tab.**

If I make a change to the code, then I should just rebuild with maven and republish.

I am aware that you can deploy an EAR in Wepshere admin web console, but it is not ear I am thinking of, at least I don't think so. I want to be able for example, once application is deployed, jRebel should be able to reload the clases in the jvm, but I believe the ear file is standalone so that wouldn't work.

So,

**How can I start the server from the command prompt, plus deploy a project and publish it ?**

Thanks!

Comment: So what to use JRebel or plain EAR deployment? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: In development I want to be able to start and deploy the application only once. If I change something in the code, I want it to be the picked up by the running server and I should be able to see the change, for example if I refresh my browser.

Comment: could you please clarify your concern about JRebel, why shouldn't it work for EAR? You just need to map the application via rebel.xml correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can automate the build so that it deploys the app as well, at least with Maven. Have a look at this post: [Maven 2 and WebSphere](http://sdudzin.blogspot.com/2007/09/maven-2-and-websphere-automated-build.html):

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere has (had?) a Rapid Deploy feature that you can use for "hot" deployments. Essentially it fired up a headless Eclipse for this, but it was much faster than a full EAR build and just as dynamic as going through WTP.

At the time, we had an Ant task that we used to copy the files over to the WRD directory. I'm not sure how that would work with Maven, but I imagine one could rig up something.